# Confused about the storage/public symbolic link

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

When I save a file, I use:

```
$request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');
```

Which saves it in the following directory:

```
storage/app/avatars
```

But my symbolic link (created by doing `php artisan storage:link`) links to:

```
storage/app/public
```

But none of my files are saved under that folder?? They're all saved under `storage/app` (like `storage/app/avatars`).

Can someone explain to me wtf this `storage/app/public` folder is there for, when I save all my files under a different directory?

Comment: The public folder will be accessible from an url. everything outside that folder will only be accessible by your server

Comment: So how do I get the path to my newly created avatar file (not a URL)?

Comment: In your public directory is there a storage dir? Which should be a sym link to app\storage

Comment: According to the docs, the symlink is to app/storage/public, which is why this makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing files in the `local` disk, but should be storing them in the `public` disk if you want this functionality.

> The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible. By default, the public disk uses the local driver and stores these files in storage/app/public. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public.
>
> Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk

You need to tell Laravel to store it in the public disk.

```
$request->file('avatar')->store('avatars', ['disk' => 'public']);
```